# How to make dynamic sld filter?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a sld style:

```
<se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name> 0 - 100 </se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title> >101 </se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>101</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name> 51- 100 </se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title> 51- 100</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>51</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#00ff00</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name> 0- 50 </se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title> 0- 50 </se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>50</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#0000ff</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
```

So depended on field `count` i got:

```
>=101  Red polygon
51-100 Green polygon
<=50   Blue polygon
```

Now i add CQL filter into wms request to show features with `count <=100`:

```
CQL_FILTER=count%3C%3D100
```

So i got Green and Blue polygons only.
And here my question.
Can i modifi my SLD to it dynamicaly change filters values? For example above, after adding CQL filter i got features with `count <=100`. And i want to filters changed like:

```
51-100 Red polygon
<=50   Green polygon
```

It possible make something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoServer provides [an `env` function](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html) that allows you to set values within the SLD using parameters passed in as part of the URL.

So your filter could become something like:

```
   <ogc:And>
      <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Function name="env">
          <ogc:Literal>low</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>51</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
        <ogc:PropertyName>count</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Function name="env">
          <ogc:Literal>high</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
    </ogc:And>
```

And then you can change them by adding `&env=low:1;high=52` to your getMap request.